# Why does calling external function pointer crash the program?

Tags: c, visual-c++

There are two source files, `a.c` and `b.c`. `a.c`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`b.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static void bar(void)
{
    puts("Hola!");
}

extern void (*foo)(void) = bar;
```

Compile them together (`cl a.c b.c`), run the program, the program will crash. Why is that?

However, a declaration like `extern void (*foo)(void);` would solve the problem.

My environment is Windows MSVC:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8804 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.
```

---

I guess it's because:

1. Since `foo` is not declared, the compiler guesses that it's a function.
2. However, `foo` is not a function, but a variable, so the calling fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `foo` is not declared, the compiler guesses that it's a function. However, `foo` is not a function, but a variable, so the calling fails.

Before C99 (*request for a check*), C does not force the user to declare functions before calling them, so there are no warnings or errors from the compiler; What's more, there is really one `foo` defined, no matter it is a variable or a function, so there are no warnings or errors from the linker. These make this issue hard to find.

However, as found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528164/implicit-declaration-in-c), sometimes an implicit function call like this would become a undefined behaviour (UB):

> **J.2 Undefined behavior**
>
> — For call to a function without a function prototype in scope where
> the function is defined with a function prototype, either the
> prototype ends with an ellipsis or the types of the arguments after
> promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters
> (6.5.2.2).

Comment: “C does not force the user to declare functions before calling them” — Actually it totally does, unless you are using a woefully outdated version of C. The problem is that *implementations* aren’t always great at following the C standard in this regard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for pointing out this, you remind me. After C99 there is a restriction, and I'm using MSVC 1998 (like c89).

Comment: @KonradRudolph C is what gets implemented, not what the standard says. As long as implicit function declarations are part of the language accepted in the default compilation mode by all widely used C compilers, they are a feature of C. Telling people they aren't only causes confusion.

Comment: @zwol I’m sympathetic regarding the confusion but I’m adamant that “C” is the *standard*. The implementations aren’t C, they’re *implementations of the standard*. This matters, because the standard is normative, the implementations aren’t. In particular, when there’s disagreement then the defect is *in the implementation*, and needs to be fixed *there*. This would matter less (or more?) if there was only one major implementation … but this isn’t the case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's a fine tack to take when filing bug reports on compilers, but that's not what we're doing here. When teaching C to beginners, which *is* what we're doing here — no language-lawyer tag on this question — you gotta take a more pragmatic view.

Comment: @zwol I totally agree with being pragmatic. But in the case of C this means teaching the rules, the actual behaviour, and about diagnostics (`-pedantic`, `-Wall` etc.).